# Как быть, встретив «ответ», который оставлен явно автором вопроса, но из-под другой учётной записи?

Tags: обсуждение, модерация

Нередко случается, что пользователь задаёт вопрос под одной учётной записью («анонимной/незарегистрированной»), а затем (войдя с другого компьютера, из другого браузера, в другой браузерной сессии) не имеет возможности ни исправить вопрос, ни ответить на комментарии других пользователей под «своим» же вопросом.

Как быть, встретив такую ситуацию?

---

Пример такой ситуации: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/483080/178576
Сейчас уже учётные записи объединены, но первоначально «ответ» (в данный момент он удалён и виден только обладателям привилегии «[инструменты модератора](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools)», для остальных привожу текст «ответа»: «Да, верно, возвращается json. Что нужно сделать в этом случае?») был отправлен из-под иной, нежели вопрос, учётной записи.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

во-первых, можно предложить пользователю воспользоваться [инструкцией по объединению учётных записей](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/merging-accounts).

во-вторых, стоит нажать кнопку «тревога» и отправить модераторам сообщение с кратким изложением ситуации. что-то вроде: «надо бы объединить учётные записи, так как автор вопроса и „ответа“ — явно один и тот же».

у модераторов нет права объединять учётные записи (согласно [информации](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26861400#26861400) от [Nofate](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/1984)). но есть право преобразовать такой «ответ» в комментарий или правку вопроса.

зато право объединять учётные записи есть у [Nicolas Chabanovsky](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/6) (согласно полученной от него [информации](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26878981#26878981)), и он также просматривает очередь «тревог».

---

и по поводу возможности отправки таких «тревог» он дополняет:

> [Можно еще на почту писать и отправлять соответствующий запрос через форму обратной связи. Через тревогу увидят все модераторы, это будет быстрее. Через форму обратной связи – только сотрудники компании (т.е. по сути, только я, если сообщение на русском языке).](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/26879095#26879095)